# How to divide tables evenly in a gridview?

Tags: android, layout, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to recreate the following layout in Android:

[image: result]

The grid does not have to grow dynamically, it will always be 5 columns & 2 rows. The orientation is fixed to landscape. Each cell has the exact same layout, just the data in the TextViews can change.

My current approach is to fill a GridLayout with TableLayouts and setting appropriate layout_row & layout_column for each TableLayout. Like so :

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:rowCount="2" 
    android:columnCount="4" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">
```

Which results in this:

[image: bad]
Code from picture above : https://pastebin.com/khr9aGWf

I'm running into a few problems.

- I cannot get the cells to automatically scale to fit the screen.
- The size of this layout file is starting to become very large and hard to manage

Perhaps my approach is completely wrong and I need to go towards something where I define the layout of a cell once and dynamically fill a grid with it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create this kind of layout using GridView

```
<GridView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:numColumns="5"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
```

your gridview item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

GridviewAdapter.java

```
    public class GridviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Activity context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    TableLayout.LayoutParams params;

    public GridviewAdapter(Activity context)
    {
        this.context=context;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        params=new TableLayout.LayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                (int) ((getDeviceHeight(context)-getStatusBarHeight()) / 2)));

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if(position%2==0)
        {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        }else{
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        }

        convertView.setLayoutParams(params);


        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {

    }

    public static int getDeviceHeight(Context context) {

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            Point point = new Point();
            wm.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);
            return point.y;
        } else {
            return wm.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        }
    }

    public int getStatusBarHeight() {
        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

and in your activity class add code like this

```
GridviewAdapter itemsAdapter = new GridviewAdapter(this);
 GridView listView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.list);
 listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

your output look like [this](http://prntscr.com/nadry1)

Comment: I've implemented your solution, but the height is not filling the screen as it should. I can still scroll up and down on my device.

Comment: can you please provide screenshot so i can get idea.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Oe4BgHV The height of the two rows are not scaling to the height of the device allowing me to scroll up and down. in the picture you can see the highest textboxes are not visible cause i scrolled down.